# SQL Multiple ID columns in the Where...IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

HI I may not use correct search keywords to find the answer on stackoverflow. Here's my question:
One table has 3 (or more) ID columns. With a list of the IDs I would like to query the table to return rows.

For example
MyTable has 3 ID columns:

```
ID1   ID2       ID3
15    567       1312
15    567       1319
21    918       1582
58    609       1444
```

In PLSQL using TUPLE we can do

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (ID1, ID2) IN ((1,2), (2,3)...);
```

But Tuple doesn't apply to this situation because there are 3 ID columns.

What I'm doing now is to concatenate the IDs in the query because IDs are numeric:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (ID1 || '-' || ID2 || '-' || ID3) IN (('15-567-1312'), ('21-918-1582')...);
```

But I'm always wondering if there is another way to do it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html) say you can "specify up to 1000 expressions in *expression_list*" - not just two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And why can't tuples have three columns?  Did you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (ID1, ID2, ID3) IN ( (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), ... );
```